# Object properties triggering error in HTML template

Tags: angular

I'm using a http request to return a single object in my Angular2 app. The object seems to be returning ok but the properties of the object aren't accessible in my view.

My Service Call:

```
  getSession(title) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/session')
      .map((response: Response) => {
        const session = response.json().obj.find(session => session.title.toLowerCase() === title);
        return session;
      })
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json));
  }
```

And the return

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.title = params['title'];
    });

    this.sessionService.getSession(this.title)
      .subscribe(
        session => {
          this.session = session
          console.log(this.session)
        });
  }
```

The object is being logged and looks fine but I'm getting a typescript error in  my return saying that this.session isn't assignable to my Session Model. `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Session'`

This leads me to believe the HTTP return object might be nested in another object so I tried creating a New Session within my Service assigning all the values there and returning that class but it seems to still have the same issue.

```
  getSession(title: string) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/session')
      .map((response: Response) => {
        const session = response.json().obj.find(session => session.title.toLowerCase() === title);
        console.log(session)
        let transformSession = (new Session(session.title, session.date, session.description, session.imageUrl, session.featuredSession, session.audioUrl, session.tracklist, null, null));
        return transformSession;
      })
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json));
  }
```

[image]

The first object is logged while in my service before I build the object with my Session class and the second one is logged in my component. They both seem valid but I can't access the properties of either.

If I use `{{session | json}}` it will print this

[image]

But if I try `{{session.title}}` I get a return error of title is undefined.

Am I missing something? I've been building all my applications with local JSON files and this is my first Angular application with a server.

Thanks

Comment: Okay so I tried console.log session.title within my component and that returns the session title correctly... But when I bring it into my HTML view it doesn't work.... Any ideas why this would be.

Comment: Ok, I added a div(*ngIf="session") to the beginning of my code and it seems to work now. Seems strange that I would need a ngIf to initialize my object. Especially since the object is already there without the ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP` doesn't know what you will get from server, it might be Session, Product, User... So it assigns generic Object type to it. Typescript on the other hand expects Session, because you declared `session: Session` and it gives you this error because of it.

You can help typescript compiler by telling it that you know method returns certain type:

```
getSession(title): Session {
  ...
}
```

or

```
  .subscribe(
    (session: Session) => {...});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! And I understand, but even if I put my return in a Session object it still gives the error. Applying that first bit should help me narrow the issue. Thanks again.